# weird result after invoking a higher order function

Tags: javascript

```
let myName = "john";

function morning(name){
  return`my name is ${name}`;
}

function pleasure(){
  return `and it is nice to meet you`;
}

function greet(name, callBack, callBack2){
  console.log(`Good Morning, ${callBack(name)} ${callBack2}`);
}

greet(myName, morning, pleasure);
```

why the result is like this ?

```
Good Morning, my name is john function pleasure(){
  console.log(`and it is nice to meet you`); ;
}
```

Comment: Because you're not invoking `callBack2`?

Comment: You never _call_ `callBack2`: `${callBack2()}`

Comment: You didn't call "callBack2", you just mentioned it.  Try adding "()"

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call your second function

```
function greet(name, callBack, callBack2){
    console.log(`Good Morning, ${callBack(name)} ${callBack2()}`); // forgot the parenthesis on callback2
}
```